Wire Management Web App Stalling Multiple Times a Day
I have a problem with one of our Web Apps in production.
About 6 months ago our Sys Admin team moved the team that was using this web app to a new windows persistent cluster in our environment.
We enabled One Drive for the users so that their data would be better maintained and able to be deployed onto the local users system and their VM.
After making this change the web app became an issue for most of the users. They reported the web page locking up for over 4 mins, randomly, with no consistency between users or amount of times per day. Some days it happens once and other days maybe over 20 times.
The only way they found to remedy the problem is to close the whole browser and reopen or wait the whole 4 mins which is far to long for them.
This occurs on both the VM and the local users PC, the VM's are located in the same office as the web app and some users are in the office too some times.
This apps main function is to upload and archive wires from other customers and when you attempt to edit, upload or save the files the issue occurs.
There is even a user who on the first day had the issue but since then hasn't had it and is only on site.
I have attempted to isolate the problem by seeing if maybe the connection to the webpage was timing out by running ping -t command to the web page address but no issues with that.
I made them try different browsers, make sure to confirm that they were off of the VM and on their own computer and still the same issues occurring.
I have disabled One Drive on systems for the whole day and no change to issues.
I am not the application manager so I am not well versed in this but what other solutions can I use to narrow down this problem?
